# MySQL Select the highest from last 50 rows

Tags: mysql

I want to select the highest `won` from my last 50 rows.
But why is that not working?

I found that in other questions but i dont know why that doesnt work for me?

This is my query with that what i tried

```
SELECT max(won) from games WHERE game ='case' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
```

I want the highest won from the last 50 rows by DESC so i order by id DESC.

But than i get the highest won of everything won, not only from the last 50 rows.

Comment: Please add sample data.  Your query may already be correct, depending on what your logic is.

Answer (score 6):

You could do the limit first and then get the max.

```
SELECT max(won) FROM
( 
  SELECT * FROM games 
  WHERE game ='case' 
  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
) AS tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with subquery:

```
select max(won)
from
(SELECT * from games WHERE game ='case' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50)a
```